# Join or Sub-query to "detect missing records"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling to get this query working.

I have 2 tables that contain a countrycode being 'US' or 'AU' or 'JP' - this is a common key.

SELECT DISTINCT cc FROM geo_world;
SELECT cc FROM geo_country;

Note: geo_world is a large table with millions of entries but only 124 distinct cc values.

Note: geo_country contains only 244 cc values.

I want to find out the cc values in geo_country that are not show in geo_world. There should be 120 of them.

thankyou - I've tried joins but failed to get the result.

Comment: I tend to favor JOINS over sub-queries as they normally "fit my head better". I am not sure how the MySQL query planner works these days, but it really ought to handle these simple cases in 2012...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, any of these should work:

```
SELECT cc
  FROM geo_country
 WHERE cc NOT IN
        ( SELECT cc                 -- or SELECT DISTINCT cc
            FROM geo_world
        )
;

SELECT cc
  FROM geo_country
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM geo_world
           WHERE cc = geo_country.cc
        )
;

SELECT geo_country.cc
  FROM geo_country
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN geo_world
    ON geo_world.cc = geo_country.cc
 WHERE geo_world.cc IS NULL             -- i.e., the join failed
;
```

But you'll have to try them to see which one performs best.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT cc
FROM geo_world
WHERE cc NOT IN (SELECT cc FROM geo_country)
```

Some notes:

1. Make sure that `geo_world` has an index that covers `cc`
2. If you need to do that on regular basis - you probably better denormalize the data and keep unused countrycodes in another small 100-or-some rows table, just as some sort of cache

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) condition. You can do this like this:

```
SELECT cc FROM geo_country WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from geo_world WHERE geo_world.cc = geo_country.cc);
```